# Как изменить подписи к осям в matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Я сделал несколько графиков, длина каждого по оси Ох = 140, но из-за того, что данные я получал с помощью срезов, значения по этой оси идут с 400 до 540. Я хочу изменить их на список значений от 0 до 140 с шагом 10. Как мне это сделать?

Кроме того, я хочу изменить значения по оси Оу с [1, 40] на другой список с сорока значениями?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно приводить свой код в вопросе, потому как не ясно, как именно вы выводите данные на холст - через api или функционально. предположим, вы делаете это функционально. Разберем пример:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.random.randint(400, 540, 50)
y = np.random.randint(400, 540, 50)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

получим то, что и ожидалось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете легко поменять шаг меток (локаторы) и их обозначение так:

```
plt.xticks(range(400, 550, 10), range(0, 150, 10))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

здесь в методе `plt.xticks()` первый аргумент - это фактическое расположение локаторов на ваших реальных данных с нужным шагом. второй аргумент - это подписи к этим локаторам (меткам) в нужном вам диапазоне, с нужным вам шагом. разумеется, и первый и второй аргументы принимают любые iterables с соответствующей размерностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично с осью `y` - через параметр `plt.yticks()`